# Css Flexbox positioning margin-top the logo problem

Tags: html, css, flexbox

im learning flexbox and i have a problem. I want to make h1,p,button the align center and also logo positioning top about margin-top 1em like that. Basically h1,p,button positioning center and logo positioning top from margin-top 1em like that.
Should i put logo outside the div.content ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: bordex-box
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.content h1 {}

.content p {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.content .button {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em 5em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <a href="" class="logo">logo</a>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur distinctio neque itaque dignissimos nesciunt quisquam architecto possimus corrupti, a molestias. Quibusdam cum eveniet minus maxime itaque consequatur adipisci, non delectus magni
    ea voluptatum</p>
  <a href="#" class="button">Register Now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: please explain what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: i want to make logo on the top but when i put logo outside the div.content my content height getting smaller

Comment: Add new container for logo with width: 100% and height whatever you want and within put your logo. I will provide soon the solution

Comment: i tried but still my content height less then 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `position:absolute` to your logo and some styling to make it stand out.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {

  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.outerbox {
display:flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.content h1 {}

.content p {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.content .button {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em 5em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="" class="logo">logo</a>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur distinctio neque itaque dignissimos nesciunt quisquam architecto possimus corrupti, a molestias. Quibusdam cum eveniet minus maxime itaque consequatur adipisci, non delectus magni
      ea voluptatum</p>
    <a href="#" class="button">Register Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: bordex-box
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.content h1 {}

.content p {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.content .button {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em 5em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="">logo</a>
  </div>

  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur distinctio neque itaque dignissimos nesciunt quisquam architecto possimus corrupti, a molestias. Quibusdam cum eveniet minus maxime itaque consequatur adipisci, non delectus magni
    ea voluptatum</p>
  <a href="#" class="button">Register Now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer and upvote if you can.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: bordex-box
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.content h1 {}

.content p {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.content .button {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  padding: 1em 5em;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="" class="logo">logo</a>
</nav>

<div class="content">
  
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur distinctio neque itaque dignissimos nesciunt quisquam architecto possimus corrupti, a molestias. Quibusdam cum eveniet minus maxime itaque consequatur adipisci, non delectus magni
    ea voluptatum</p>
  <a href="#" class="button">Register Now</a>
</div>
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: thakns but no, i want to make my content height: 100vh. but when i put my logo outsite div.content my height getting smaller. I want to make content 100vh also my logo  top maybe  1em like that and text-align center

Comment: So I think I understand what you want to do.

Comment: Try for .content class height: calc(100vh-80px). This 80px is the height of your navbar (you need to specify height of navbar).

Comment: Yes as @ArcMech suggested, adjusting content height isn't a bad idea. +1 as I have done this before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to put the logo outside content div or you have to resort to adding margins or padding which isn't recommended.

Comment: but when i put the logo outside my content height getting smaller so my new height doesn't 100vh

Comment: you can always add some padding in the div.